# Android TV - resume already started content from home

Tags: android, android-tv

I am new to Android TV programming and just managed to have an App that starts a video from an ExoPlayer implementation.
When I hit the HOME-button the home is shown and the content I started appears in the purple marked area. I can resume my App from here.

[TV Emulator - Android 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSlCf.jpg)

Can you tell me how this area is called?
How can I control which meta data is shown?

I only found information about the Watch Next Card, but it seems to be something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems to be the notification area. It's not exclusive to playback.
For example, notifications for a firmware update will also appear there.

To have a proper now playing car and display metadata and other info see this:
https://developer.android.com/training/tv/playback/now-playing.html